# How is this fluid column layout changing to single-column as page narrows?

Tags: css, layout, fluid

Can someone explain how http://cssgrid.net/ achieves the effect that when the browser width is below a certain amount, the layout switches from 3-column to single-column?

I've tried turning off javascript, and inspecting the CSS of `.row` and `.container` but my knowledge of CSS is lacking. There's a `min-width` property but changing it via Firebug doesn't seem to affect much.

Could someone point out what in the CSS is causing the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ben; for this need to use `mediaqueries` .It's new property in which we define the css according to the width. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/apx.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/new-css.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" title="no title" />
```

In the above example the `apx.css` is your default css & and `new-css.css` apply when your screen width decrease to 600px.

That a best link for your answer http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Check this for more http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 3):

It's the media queries at the bottom of the [main CSS](http://cssgrid.net/css/1140.css):

```
/* Smaller screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    ...
}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    ...
}
```

These apply different rules based on the browser dimensions, and are helped out by a [JS class](http://cssgrid.net/js/css3-mediaqueries.js) for older browsers.

Comment: +1 for actually looking at the CSS of the site in question rather than another unrelated site's.